# How many odd numbers of $5$ digits can be formed with the digits $0,2,3,4,5$ without repetition of any digit?

Tags: combinatorics

How many odd numbers of $5$ digits can be formed with the digits $0,2,3,4,5$ without repetition of any digit?

I noticed that the last number can be filled in $2$ ways and first place can be filled in $3$ ways. Consequently, 2nd 3rd and 4th places can be filled in $3$, $2$ and $1$ ways respectively. Is there any flaw in this reasoning? Please guide further.

Comment: $\color{green}\checkmark\quad$ You are good to go.

Comment: I will warn you about naming things "permutations" but then treating them as different objects.  The phrasing of the question in the body is correct and unambiguous (*"how many odd numbers of 5 digits..."*), but the concept of an "odd permutation" is distinctly different than that of an odd number.  For example, 52340 is an odd *permutation* of the digits when treated as a permutation of $\{0,2,3,4,5\}$ despite being an even *number*.  If in doubt of whether something should be referred to as a permutation, "arrangement" is a more generic term which is usually valid and often more appropriate.

Comment: ...(*odd permutation here in the algebraic sense as in the permutation can be expressed as the product of an odd number of transpositions*)

Answer (score 1):

$\color{green}\checkmark\quad$ You are good to go.

We count ways to select from the two odd digits for the units, from the three other non-zero digits for ten-thousandth place, and how to arrange the three remaining digits in the remaining places.   Then we go forth and mulltiply. $$2\cdot 3\cdot 3! ~=~ 36$$